# error in tally function in R

Tags: r, count

I have a table like below and I want to count the `"POL"` by ST,CRO, PL, PRA, FUN,SCD.

Please see the `Output` below. I have following script but it does not provide the Output I need.

```
Output <- tally(group_by(Table,POL,ST,CRO, PL, PRA, FUN,SCD))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Table:

DIV ST  POL    CRO PL  CTY FUN PRA  LEV  LIA   PRM  R_L LOS SCD
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 1482  331  0   0   10/02
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 10549 1785 0   0   10/02
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 679   115  0   0   10/02
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 1329  225  0   0   10/02
1   24  49     88  13   79 COM 5300 0.90 15214 2647 0   0   11/15
1   24  49     88  13   79 COM 5350 0.90 15214 3346 0   0   11/15
1   14  11761  33  90  157 COM   30 0.70 7277  394  0   0   10/02
1   24  15672   11  2   41 COM   30 0.75 7662  1091 0   0   10/02
1   24  15675   11  2   41 COM   30 0.70 16251 1869 0   0   10/02


Output:

ST  CRO PL  FUN PRA  SCD   POL_Count
14  33  90  COM 7130 10/02        1
24  88  13  COM 5300 11/15        1
24  88  13  COM 5350 11/15        1
14  33  90  COM  30  10/02        1
24  11  2   COM  30  10/02        2
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `tally` as you don't want to count observations by group, but unique `POL` values by group. Also, `POL` shouldn't be part of your grouping variables. You want to create the groups first and then count unique `POL` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text = "DIV ST  POL    CRO PL  CTY FUN PRA  LEV  LIA   PRM  R_L LOS SCD
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 1482  331  0   0   10/02
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 10549 1785 0   0   10/02
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 679   115  0   0   10/02
1   14  3      33  90  101 COM 7130 0.75 1329  225  0   0   10/02
1   24  49     88  13   79 COM 5300 0.90 15214 2647 0   0   11/15
1   24  49     88  13   79 COM 5350 0.90 15214 3346 0   0   11/15
1   14  11761  33  90  157 COM   30 0.70 7277  394  0   0   10/02
1   24  15672   11  2   41 COM   30 0.75 7662  1091 0   0   10/02
1   24  15675   11  2   41 COM   30 0.70 16251 1869 0   0   10/02",
header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)


dt %>% 
  group_by(ST, CRO, PL, PRA, FUN, SCD) %>%
  summarise(POL_Count = n_distinct(POL)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#      ST   CRO    PL   PRA FUN   SCD   POL_Count
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>     <int>
# 1    14    33    90    30 COM   10/02         1
# 2    14    33    90  7130 COM   10/02         1
# 3    24    11     2    30 COM   10/02         2
# 4    24    88    13  5300 COM   11/15         1
# 5    24    88    13  5350 COM   11/15         1
```

Comment: I am not getting a table from your code. I get the output as  POL_Count
1         5

Comment: So, you run the code I posted and you get a different result?

Comment: I am NOT getting your output Table. I get the out as                          POL_Count
1         5

Comment: Not sure how this is possible. Start a new R session and run it again.

Comment: Yes. it worked. Thanks. Also, Can you please tell me a way or how can I modify your code to sum the columns (LIA, PRM, R_L, LOS) by the distinct POLs?

Comment: Try this: `dt %>%
  group_by(POL) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(LIA, PRM, R_L, LOS), sum)`